# iptables drop to keep ports silent with no response

Tags: networking, iptables, firewalld

I am working on the network telescope stuffs (AKA. darknet, black hole), which need to make the port take no response to outer traffic (ie. when other servers PING or send SYN requests, my server should note this packet but without responding SYN, RST etc messages). So I decided to configurate my iptables and firewall to drop the traffic I respond. As I need to log in the server through SSH by port 22, the port 22s's request and communication should be reserved.

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --sport 22 -j DROP
```

After I typed this code in command line, I lose the connection with my server. Why this code would result in the disconnection of SSH? And What should I do to restore the connection with my server? And what should I do to implement the ignorance to outer traffic and take no  respond to traffic except SSH?

Comment: Next time, I would suggest using `iptables-apply` before you try configuring any iptables that potentially result in you losing your SSH connection. `iptables-apply` will ask you if you can still open NEW connections to your server, and if you don't respond within its timeout period, will restore the previous iptables configuration, preventing a lockout.

Answer (score 3):

A TCP connection uses one port on the server side, (22 in your case) and one on the client side that is not a well-known port but an ephemeral port (in Linux, above 32768). From the point of view of server, that ephemeral port is the OUTPUT port, so you have closed current connections and avoiding future ones if local port of the client is different from  22.

To fix this mess, you should log into the server with an SSH connection using the LocalPort=22 option. Assuming that you can use openssh:

```
ssh -p 22 -o "LocalPort=22" [username]@[server-address]
```

Of course, while you are trying to log into the server, the client's port 22 would be dedicated to this connection, meaning the client could not, in turn, run an SSH server in port 22.

Once in the server, first thing should be (if the rule you have configured is the only one in the server)

```
sudo iptables -F OUTPUT
```

And then I suggest using a virtual machine to test any other configuration ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ssh backets coming BACK from the ssh server have a DESTINATION port of 22, not a source port. Also, you can't probe other hosts if you can't send packets.

If this were my task, then I would be blocking all incoming packets (other than ssh) which do not have a SYN flag.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: Actually, a pure network telescope implementation should not send packets to others. It just listen and accept other's traffic but do nothing. So in my view, we need to drop all the traffic that my server should respond (ie. SYN, ACK, RST, etc.) (of course other than SSH to keep connection).

Comment: So simples: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT ; iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT`